# Passing functors and function pointers interchangeably using a templated method in C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, functor

I currently have a templated class, with a templated method. Works great with functors, but having trouble compiling for functions.

Foo.h

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
   public:
   // Constructor, destructor, etc...
   template <typename Func>
   void bar(T x, Func f);
};

template <typename T>
template <typename Func>
void Foo<T>::bar(T x, Func f) { /* some code here */ }
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
template <typename T>
class Functor {
    public:
    Functor() {}
    void operator()(T x) { /* ... */ }
    private:
    /* some attributes here */
};

template <typename T>
void Function(T x) { /* ... */ } 

int main() {
   Foo<int> foo;
   Functor<int> F;
   foo.bar(2, F); // No problem
   foo.bar(2, Function); // <unresolved overloaded function type>
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than one function named `Function`?

Comment: `void Function(T x) { /* ... */ } ` is not a template, so what is `T`?

Comment: @JesseGood You are correct, thanks. Will update the question. It is an integer actually.

Comment: @metroxylon: If you change it to `int`, the code [works fine](http://ideone.com/naWCk).

Comment: Can't reproduce; this compiles for me.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was indeed a templated function.

Comment: Called it like: foo.bar(2, Function<int>) and compiles now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a function pointer for an overloaded function, you need to tell the system which function out of the overload set you want:

```
foo.bar(2, static_cast<void(*)(int)>(&Function);
```

In the quoted case the function is actually a template, i.e., you can also refer to its specialization directly:

```
foo.bar(2, &Function<int>);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. The second line to be specific. However, I just used: foo.bar(2, Function<int>); and worked. What is the difference. Is it purely syntactic?

Comment: @metroxylon : `&Function<int>` is a function pointer, `Function<int>` is a function that will immediately decay into a function pointer when passed into `foo.bar`. So yes, in this case, the `&` is either syntactic noise or syntactic clarification depending on your perspective.